# How to browse available payment extensions?

Tags: extension, payment-processor

The extensions directory lists various extensions, but I don't see a way to filter by purpose. I'm looking for payment extension options.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/index lists 208 extensions, but gives no indication or easy way to filter by purpose.

https://civicrm.org/extensions and some of the other URLs show no extensions at all, even if I hit submit on a blank form or put a single vowel into the "name" field (which I'd expect to see *some* results for). (This might just be a bug so isn't really part of my question!)

This seems like an obvious feature for a directory - what am I missing?

Comment: Also I suspect the option "Modify Entity Values" should not be available at https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm? I don't have an account on that site.

Comment: That is a very good point though about how the Extensions directory works and how it could be improved with the categories like "Payment processors extensions" etc. I will bring up that idea during next partner meeting to suggest such a change because I've been actually thinking about this every time I had to search that directory.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to selecting a suiting payment processors I would recommend having a look at [this page](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Payment+Processors).

Also, make sure to read any documentation you can find on those payment processors intersting to you, such as:

- Developers Website
- Extension's Githup Page
- CiviCRM Wiki
- ...

Make sure it is compatible with your version of CiviCRM and does not have major bugs that prevent you from using it.